# "ORA-12541: TNS:no listener"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've tried all day to fix this issue with solutions suggested on the web, but none of them worked.

I am trying to set up the Oracle database on my PC for remote connections. It works for local connections, but I'm trying to make it work for all connections.

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my_ip )(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = xe)));
```

My listener is started and its content is:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\Programs\Oracle\oracledatabasexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\Programs\Oracle\oracledatabasexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

I am using Oracle Database Express Edition 11g.

I tried to connect from the same PC the database server is on and from another PC, but on the same network. I got the "TNS:no listener" error on the two computers.

Having some help would be very nice, because I'm a bit desperate right now.

Edit:
This is what I get for the  lsnrctl status command:

```
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                22-JANV.-2017 12:11:28
Uptime                    0 days 11 hr. 30 min. 18 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   F:\Programs\Oracle\oracledatabasexe\app\oracle\product
\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         F:\Programs\Oracle\oracledatabasexe\app\oracle\diag\tn
slsnr\Jean-Simon-PC\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Jean-Simon-PC)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Jean-Simon-PC)(PORT=8080))(Presentat
ion=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `HOST = 0.0.0.0` doesn't look right to me. 127.0.0.1 perhaps? Or the name or IP address of the computer on which the listener is running.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm still getting the same error with 127.0.0.1 and restarting the listener

Comment: This question would probably be better off on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you open your firewall for external connections?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 won't work on external servers. You need to enter the IP of the Oracle server?

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked listener status. local connections don't use  listener to connect database. but remote use it. check it using **lsnrctl status**.if get TNS:no listener use **lsnrctl start** to start it.